# How can I find the historical stock price for a specific stock on a specific date?

Tags: stocks, markets

I am looking for an old stock price of a company that subsequenty has merged with another company.  I am looking for the stock price of Union Electric (UEP) on Oct. 12, 1992.

Answer (score 7):

Go to a large reference library and ask to see the *Wall Street Journal* for October 13 1992.

Answer (score 2):

I've had luck finding old stock information in the [Google scanned newspaper archives](https://news.google.com/newspapers). Unfortunately there does not appear to be a way to [search exactly by date](https://support.google.com/news/answer/1638638?hl=en&rd=1), but a little browsing /experimenting should get what you want. For instance, here's [a source](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=JVJ6OkSwpHsC&dat=19921013&printsec=frontpage&hl=en) which shows the price to be 36 3/4 (as far as I can read anyway) on that date.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search showed me that UEP merged into Ameren on Dec 31, 1997, and Ameren still exists today.  So I took a look at Ameren's Investor Relations website.   Unfortunately, they don't provide historical stock prices prior to Ameren forming, so starting with 1998.  However, I've had good luck in the past emailing a company's investor relations contact and asking for data like this that isn't on the website.  It's reasonably likely they'll have internal records they could look it up within.